# R does not exist after rename application

Tags: android, package, rename

This question has been asked before, but for some reason it never gets totally answered.  Usually people just recommend rebuilding the project, which doesn't work in my case.  I renamed the package from com.example.my.package to something like com.my.new.package.  What happened though is it refactored everything and then said R can't be found.  All the references to resources are from my old package name.  so I see things like:

findViewById(com.example.package.R.id.imageGallery);

All I need to do is make those resourcess say:

com.my.new.package.R.id.imageGallery.

Where do I tell Android Studio to do this?  I also already changed the name at the top of the manifest and the gradle file.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you change the values manually or did you use Android Studio to automatically change the values?

Comment: I ended up manually doing it.  Which I regret now.  It looks like I can add the package name at the top and then just erase the junk before R.id....  I'm going to have to do this about 100 times, so if you know a better way, I'm open to it.  I'm also hoping that will solve all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a lot of issues changing the package name.

Since you did it manually, you have two options.

1. Revert back to a version of your code before the change and then use Android Studio to set it manually.
2. Use the Android Studio `Replace in Path` function. `Edit -> Find -> Replace in Path`. `Scope` your whole project. Set the `Text to find` as your old package name and the `Replace with text` as your new package name. Click `Find` and cross your fingers.

Comment: I had to do opposite way. I renamed automatically package name and after that R was not found any more. Source files where in the new place. I had to change and add import to old package name for R. Very, very irritating!

Answer (score 0):

Knossos's method looks a lot easier.  And hopefully you won't need to cross your fingers.  If someone comes across this problem in the future, the main things to do are to refactor the project name in the manifest, even if you've changed it already manually.  If you have a situation like mine, this will automatically refactor almost everything.  You will then have to add "import your.NEW.project.R;"  to each of your activities, and simply delete any leading reference such as "your.OLD.project.R.id.yourView", to any of your resource identifiers, so that it reads "R.id.yourView".  You may also need to update the gradle project id.  But I believe that was also refactored automatically.  It may seem overwhelming, but it's really not that bad, even if you do it manually.